# Is it possible to write multilingual website without repeating code in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multilingual

I need to write one 2 language website, one in English and another one in Danish. The data to be shown will be stored in json format, separately like **name.en** and **name.de**. There will be two buttons, one for for English and one for Danish.

But i don't want the coding like

```
<p ng-show="english">{{name.en}}</p> 
<p ng-show="danish">{{name.de}}</p>
```

and also i don't to code want like

```
 <div ng-switch on="isExists(item)">
        <span ng-switch-when="true">{{name.en}}</span>
        <span ng-switch-default>{{name.en}}</span>
       <span ng-switch-when="false">{{name.de}}</span>
 </div>
```

Where i am repeating the same code with English and Danish separately.
I want to show it with a single line. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Store  your text in a database table. It can even be something like SQLite3, which is very light. Then pull the language based on the browser's set language culture code.

Comment: i don't want the browser's set language culture code, i need like when the english button, english should be shown and on click of danish, danish should be shown

Comment: In that case you should store your text in some sort of storage. XML file, database or even a hardcoded JSON object. If you put your bilingual text in some sort of storage you won't have to worry about duplicate text on the Angular template at all.

Comment: @snowYetis You mean, it is not possible to write it in single line for both using json

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you... You want to go into a Stack chat room real quick. I believe we can solve this.

Comment: there are a few different angular libraries that focus specifically on Translation and Localization.  probably the most popular being https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate.

Comment: Nevermind, not eligible yet. Anyways, all you need to do is store your languages in JSON, as you stated. Then have that button load your JSON object. Do you want to know how to parse the JSON object and display the text on the page, after you have clicked the button?

Comment: In that case, you simply bind that button's text with JSON data and on click , after performing your task  just changed the binded JSON value.

Comment: @NaveenSingh , Could you show me how to do that with this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/1Nlgy8IoRD7WCrrFWtsG?p=preview

Comment: @Thilak Raj, angular code is not working in plunker, it seems i don't have rights to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple example 
**Html**

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setLanguage('en')">English</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setLanguage('de')">Danish</button>
<p>{{name[language]}}</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
  //inside controller
    $scope.language='en';  //initial default value
    $scope.setLanguage = function(language) {
        $scope.language = language;    
       }
```

Comment: use pascalprecht.translate to translate. very easy and fast. it just need you make a json file for each language with the translation inside.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, It is possible with the help of `angular-translate`.
Inject `'pascalprecht.translate'` as module dependency in your angular app.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['pascalprecht.translate']);
```

create a config section which will hold the json data.

```
app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        'Logout': 'Logout',
        'Login': 'Login'
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('de', {
        'Logout': 'DeLogOut',
        'Login': 'DeLogIn'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});
```

In your controller inject `$translate` as dependency to change language dynamically.

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
         $translate.use(key); // key as 'en' or 'de'
     };
```

In your partial use `translate` directive.

```
<h2 translate="">Log In</h2>
```

to get json data from api

```
var testApp = angular.module("app");
function fetchData() {
  var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]),                               $http = initInjector.get("$http");
  return $http.get('/api/getJson', {'cache':false}).then(function(response) {
  testApp.constant("appConstants", response.data);
 }, function(errorResponse) {
  });
 }
```

for more info please refer https://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: i am using api data for the content for english and danish which is in json format. how to create config section for it with the api data

Comment: create a constant to get api data and inject the same constant in your config

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a function in your scope called translate, that takes an object as a parameter (argument?), the object could be like

```
{ english: "thank you", portuguese: "obrigado" }
```

the translate function confirms the value of the language setting from a Service/Factory, and renders the word in the correct language.

The factory could be something like:

```
app.Factory("LanguageFactory", function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.language = "english"; //of course, it's english
    return obj;
});
```

Your controller could make use of the factory like:

```
app.controller("", function ($scope, LanguageFactory) {
    $scope.language = LanguageFactory;
    $scope.translate = function (word) {
        if ($scope.language == 'english') {
           return word.english;
        }
        else if ($scope.language == 'french') {
           return word.french;
        } // could go on and on
        //an alternative would be
        return word[$scope.language];
        //but to use to alternative, you would need to know what format the
        //json is returned in 
    }
});
```

I think that should work. So, everywhere in ur html that you want your multilingual functionality to work, you can display it like

```
<p>{{translate(name)}}</p>
```

Oh, i forgot, you'd need to provide a way to change the value of the lanaguage object in the Factory. This might work:

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function (l) {
     $scope.language.language = l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/) for that

Hope this will helps